# Armature deform, animate a box

Tags: animation, armature, bones

I'm very new to Blender and I'm play around with the armature deform.
I'm try to animate the opening of a box.

The animation look properly working in pose mode.

[image: Animation In Blender]

The issue is when I export the project in glb format and try to open it with other software (like Reality Converter) I get the animation totally wrong.

[image: Wrong]

For sure is due to some mistake on the application of the bone / armature, but I really don't know what to correct

How can I fix this?

Comment: best help would be to provide your blend file so we can check it out

Comment: maybe you should create another bone for the rest of the object?

Comment: Without your file provided, we can only guess, but as @moonboots says, this may be due to fact that you only use one bone that acts like a root, maybe you should make root bone under this bone and rotate the bone that is attached to root bone (maybe it will solve this issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create an armature with 2 bones: Lid and Box. Parent Lid to Box. Parent the box object to the armature with the *Empty Groups* mode. Select the vertices that are supposed to be controlled by the lid bone and go into the *Object Data panel > Vertex Groups*, select Lid and click *Assign*. Same thing for the box vertices.

[image]

[image]

Comment: ohhhh... the issue was exactly that.. thanks a lot.. appreciate ... I did't have the system with 2 bones .. but only once...